# Integrating a Countdown timer inside an alert pop up React native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a pop up ,inside it I should have the Countdown Timer

```
const onclick = () =>
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: true},
);
```

I'm calling this function in the button after clicking on it :

```
<Button mode="contained" onPress={onclick} style={homeStyle.Button}>
        <Text style={homeStyle.TextButton}>PANIC</Text>
      </Button>
```

I want to add  the CountdownCircle inside the alert but I don't know how:

```
<CountdownCircle
        seconds={10}
        radius={30}
        borderWidth={8}
        color="#ff003f"
        bgColor="#fff"
        textStyle={{ fontSize: 20 }}
        onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('Elapsed!')}
    />
```

Comment: Please use code instead screenshot

Comment: Use Modal instead of alert, and show it whenever it is needed.

Comment: Can you add it in the answer please with more details please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put React component inside `Alert`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert

Comment: I want to put an alert or pop up and inside it the countdown circle what to do?

Comment: use custom `Alert` component

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are rendered by the operating system and can only show text. You probably want to write your own pop-up component, and then use state to conditionally display it.

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

return (
  ...
  <Button onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
    <Text style={homeStyle.TextButton}>PANIC</Text>
  </Button>
  ...
  <Modal
    visible={modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}
  >
    <Text>Alert message</Text>
    <CountdownCircle /* your props here */ />
  </Modal>
  ...
);
```

See the [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) documentation for more details.

Comment: I'll try it Thank you ^^